# Демаршаллинг XML

Tags: java, xml, xmlparser

Есть XML-структура вида:
`<Group>
    <ObjA>
        <field 1></field 1>
        <field 3></field 3>
    </ObjA>
    <ObjB>
        <some field>
    </ObjB>
</Group>`

и java-классы:

```
XStreamAlias("ObjA")
public class ObjA {
    int field1;
    int field2;
    int field3;

    public ObjA() {
        field1 = 1;
        field2 = 2;
        field3 = 3;
    };
}

XStreamAlias("ObjB")
public class ObjB {
    ...
}

XStreamAlias("Group")
public class Group {
    ObjA objA;
    ObjB objB;
}
```

Если получать `_objA_` отдельно от `_objB_`, то при использовании `_xStream.fromXML(String xml, Object root)_` значение в `field2` сохраняется. Но если получать объект `_Group_`, то в `_objA_` и `_objB_` просветятся только те поля, которые указаны в `XML`, а остальные будут `_null_`.

Как можно убедить `_xStream_` не занулять поля?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взял библиотеку XStream 1.4.8 (+ xmlpull 1.1.3.1, xpp3_min 1.1.4c)
Проверил - разницы между получением Group и отдельно ObjA/ObjB не заметил - всегда ставит null (или 0 для int) для значений которых нет в xml.

Если инициализировать так:

```
XStream xStream = new XStream();
```

В таком случае XStream выбирает сам ReflectionProvider, которым обычно является Sun14ReflectionProvider. В таком случае и получается null/0 при отсутствии значения в xml.

Чтобы не затрагивались поля которых нет в xml, нужно указать провайдер PureJavaReflectionProvider:

```
XStream xStream = new XStream(new PureJavaReflectionProvider());
```

В таком случае значения установленные при инициализации поля или в конструкторе останутся.

Comment: изначально инициализировалось так: `XStream  xStream = new XStream(new DomDriver());`. Ваш вариант с `new PureJavaReflectionProvider()` помог, спасибо!